# The loop with the space variable is leaving me puzzled?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Enter the Name,Reg no and marks of the students");
    for(int i=0;i<no_students;i++)
    {
        name[i]=br.readLine();
        len=name[i].length();
        if(len<8)
        {
            space=8-len;
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=space;j++)
        {
            name[i]=name[i]+" ";
        }
        reg[i]=br.readLine();
        marks[i]=br.readLine();

    }
```

What does the counter variable j do? and what is the use of space variable?

Comment: Who wrote this code? He may know why and what.

Comment: if name has less than 8 characters it is filled with spaces until the name contains exactly 8 characters.

Comment: The counter variable j counts ! And apparently this part of the code appends as many spaces as specified by the `space` variable. Seeing how `space` is created, it is trying to make each name at least 8 characters long, by padding with spaces. This is ugly, because it could be done simply with String.format("%-8s", name[i]).

Comment: But guys, the variable space is not actually getting used anywhere in the code, it is just present in the loop, that's it..

And the worse part is that the code runs without any error INCLUDING the space padding where "space" is never actually used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, lets walk through it:

```
name[i]=br.readLine();
len=name[i].length();
```

`name[i]` - we'll call it `name` for simplicity - is now equal to the read line, `len` is equal to its length.

```
if(len<8)
{
    space=8-len;
}
```

If the length of the name is shorter than `8` then set space to the amount by which it is shorter. So if the name is `6` characters long, `space = 8 - 6 = 2`

```
for(int j=1;j<=space;j++)
{
    name[i]=name[i]+" ";
}
```

For each space, so if space is `2` this loops twice, append " " to `name`.

The basic aim of the code is to make each `name` at least `8` characters long, and if it is shorter then right-pad it.

This code commits the cardinal sin of string concatenation in a loop, this is incredibly inefficient and should always be avoided.

This code also seems to have a bug, `space` is only set in the `if` and it is not declared in the loop.  Taking `2` and `10` as an example, if a name is `2` characters long `space` will be set to `6`. The next iteration, if the name is `10` characters long the `if` will be skipped and the `10` character long name will be right-padded by `6` spaces.

Further note that this can all be accomplished used `String.format` and the format `%-8s`, which will format as a string and right-pad up to `8` characters:

```
name[i] = String.format("$-8s", br.readLine());
```

And one more important point is that this code is storing an object in parallel arrays, this is never the answer in OO code. An `Object` should be used.

In short, being as you don't understand it anyway, delete it and start again.

Comment: Why would a name with 10 characters be padded with 6 spaces, again please?

Comment: Read my explanation again, carefully, and follow it through the code as I have done. There is no magic here, just very simple code.  Take a piece of paper and a pen and walk through the logic. If you know how, you can use a debugger - which is basically just fancy paper.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this pads the name variable to `8`characters using space

The variable `j` counts the number of spaces needed to make 8 in total

**Note**-
This is not the best way to do it. Each invocation of `name[i] = name[i] + " ";` Makes a new string object. You should use a `StringBuilder` or use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`

Example:

```
name[i] = StringUtils.rightPad(name[i], 8, ' ')
```

Comment: Why recommend that a rookie programmer import a random library when there are already countless way built into Java to accomplish this goal. Doesn't quite deserve a downvote, but still very poor advice.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are right - String.format() is a better way to do this. Although in my defense, Apache Commons is not that random.

Comment: I would argue that almost all functionality the commons offers has been superseded by a combination of Java 8 and Google Guava. I think, for the most part, commons is obsolete and should be avoided. Especially Lang.

Answer (score 0):

It is filling the name variable with empty spaces if the length of name < 8.

For example, my name is Madhur, it will be stored as
'M','a','d','h','u','r',' ', ''

Space variables does not represent the character ' '.

Instead, space is a integer, which contains the number of spaces required to be filled. For example, in my name
space = 8 - 6 = 2

Hence loop will run two times to fill the 7th and 8th spot with character ''

Comment: BUt Madhur, the variable space is only used up in the initialization of the for loop not actually in the loop. Inside the for loop we are just using the good old fashioned " " ??
Then why use space at all?

Comment: See my updated answer, space is an integer which represent number of times loop will run